# Bash sort strings from an specific char

Tags: bash, sorting

I have several rows of strings, and I want to sort them alphabetically, from the character @ forward.

I give you an example, I have this:

```
alice@example.com
austin@microsoft.com
berto@example.com
charles@test.com
dorian@microsoft.com
```

and I expect this output

```
alice@example.com
berto@example.com
austin@microsoft.com
dorian@microsoft.com
charles@test.com
```

So that they are sorted by the string after the "@"

Regards!

Comment: Try `sort -t@ -k2`. And also `man sort` to read the `sort` manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sort` command for this:

```
sort -t@ -k2 inputfile
```

- -t sets the delimiter to the `@` character
- -k2 use the second column to sort

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Input list of strings separated by rows
strings=$(cat <<EOF
foo@bar
baz@qux
apple@banana
grape@cherry
EOF
)

# Sort the strings alphabetically after the "@" symbol
sorted_strings=$(echo "$strings" | sort -t "@" -k 2 | awk -F "@" '{print $1 "@" $2}')

# Print the sorted strings
echo "Sorted list of strings:"
echo "$sorted_strings"
```

Using the sort command, specifying the "@" symbol as the field separator (-t "@") and the second field (-k 2) for sorting. Next, we use awk to split the sorted output back into two fields using "@" as the field separator (-F "@"), and print the fields with "@" concatenated again.

Comment: The `echo XX |` is useless, and `awk` does nothing here. Only the `sort` is necessary in your command, which is already in other answers.

Comment: If you do a `sort -t "@" -k 2 <<<$strings`, you don't need the child process with the `echo`. Of course as _Bruno_ said, you can drop the pipe to `awk` as well.